# Does this distribution family exist?

Tags: distributions, constraint

Let $D$ be a one-parameter distribution family whose support is the positive reals.  Let $D_x$ be a distribution from this family parametrized by its mean $x \ge 0$, let $X \sim D_x$ and $Y \sim D_y$ where $X$ is independent of $Y$, and suppose
$$P(X > Y) = \frac{1}{1+e^{y-x}}.$$

Does this distribution family exist?  What is it?

Comment: You (confusingly) appear to use identical notations for a random variable and its distribution.  Let $X,Y$ be the random variables with distributions $D_x,D_y$ respectively: are you assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: @whuber, you're right, that was confusing.  Yes, I'm assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: If $y-x=3$ then the probability that $X>Y$ would be near $1/20$ regardless of the absolute sizes of $y$ and $x.$ So if $y = 1\,\,000\,\,003$ and $x = 1\,\,000\,\,000$ then that probability would be the same as if $y=4$ and $x=1.$ So it seems to me the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ would have to have small standard deviations that do not change much as $x$ and $y$ grow.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good insight, thanks.  Maybe if we get rid of the positive support bit, this is easier?